# Which CQL version corresponds to which Cassandra version?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql

The CQL documentation is organized according to the CQL version, not the Cassandra product version. Obviously, I want to read the CQL documentation corresponding to the Cassandra release I'm using, but I can't find comprehensive info on which CQL version corresponds to which Cassandra version:

- [CQL 3.1 documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cqlReferenceTOC.html) is titled "CQL for Cassandra 2.0 & 2.1", but newer CQL docs no longer mention Cassandra versions
- The [Product compatibility](http://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/compatibility.html) page only maps versions of OpsCenter, Cassandra and DataStax Enterprise

Is there a simple page listing the version mapping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for the feedback. The DataStax docs team has added a new section to the Product Compatibility page in all the docs as a result of your feedback:

```
CQL versions used by DataStax Enterprise and Cassandra 

CQL version           Cassandra         DataStax Enterprise
3.3                   2.2, 3.0,3.x      5.0
3.1                   2.0, 2.1          4.0, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7, 4.8
3.0                   1.2               3.1, 3.2
```

http://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/compatibility.html?scroll=compatibilityDocument__cql-versions

Feel free to tweet additional feedback at @DataStaxDocs

Answer (score 6):

```
CQL Version  | Cassandra Version

3.3          | 2.2 and above
3.1          | 2.o & 2.1
3.0          | 1.2 to 1.x
```

[CQL older version](http://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/archivedDocuments.html).
[CQL 3.3](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cqlIntro.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a running Cassandra data base, you can run

```
SELECT cql_version, release_version FROM system.local;
```

to get your Cassandra version and corresponding CQL version.