# Cassandra 3.9 and CQL spec version

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, cassandra-3.0

Just curious what versions of cql are supported in Cassandra 3.9.
I know that cql 3.4.2 is supported in Cassandra 3.9, but whether 3.4.3 is supported too? and how to upgrade/config Cassandra 3.9 to use cql 3.4.3?

I searched on Internet, I found some information such as [Which CQL version corresponds to which Cassandra version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38140509/which-cql-version-corresponds-to-which-cassandra-version), https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/compatibility.html, and so on, but these posts can not help me.

Any comments welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Just curious what versions of cql are supported in Cassandra 3.9

CQL adheres to [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/), meaning that a server supporting 3.4.2 should support anything in the range [3.0, 3.4.2].

> but whether 3.4.3 is supported too? and how to upgrade/config Cassandra 3.9 to use cql 3.4.3?

A given version of Cassandra has a fixed maximum CQL spec. For 3.9, it is 3.4.2, as you point out. There is no way to configure a higher version. To get features from the next CQL spec requires upgrading Cassandra (note that all [the changes for 3.4.3](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/changes.html#id1) have fixVer=3.10)